# Air Korea rebooking options after Wuhan coronavirus outbreak

Tags: bookings, event-based-effects, korean-air, skyteam, covid-19

I have a trip planned for Singapore that is currently booked with China Eastern (JFK-PVG-SIN) for early March and hsa a very high chance of ultimately being cancelled given present conditions of coronavirus 2019-nCoV.  I can get a full refund for the ticket, or change dates, but they've said they can't rebook/reroute me on other SkyTeam airlines if the flight is ultimately cancelled.

Since I'd rather not be stuck with rebooking a week or so in advance and pay the exhorbitant extra price that goes with it, I've been looking at alternate routes.

I can rebook with Korean Air or Delta for a JFK-ICN-SIN route (codeshared).  All else equal, I would normally book with Korean because I'd get extra MQD on the conversion, but I know that in the event there are problems, Delta is able to quickly reroute me with SkyTeam partners like Air France or KLM (something I've experienced now on several transatlantic flights).

If something were to happen to cause a problem with the JFK-ICN-SIN flight, would Korean Air be willing/able to reroute me through another SkyTeam partner or would I be stuck with refund/rebook on KA only?

Comment: If they have to cancel the flight, they should rebook you for free. I don't quite get why they say they can't rebook you in that case. You'll be stuck with the fees if you rebook before the flight is cancelled.

Comment: @MichaelHampton China Eastern is refunding all flights currently without fees.  They said they'd rebook me for free but only on other CE flights — of which there's only a single one a day from JFK.  I asked them specifically about using a SkyTeam partner flight instead and they said they couldn't do that

Comment: OK, that's extremely odd; any SkyTeam member should be able to rebook onto any other SkyTeam member's flights. I wonder what sort of excuse they're going to give for why they won't.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.